# MarkLogic 8 mem:node-replace

Tags: xquery, marklogic

My data contains some ID's I need to keep secret. I'd like to use the hash function with a private key and that works fine. But when I try to replace the node in-memory I can't get it to work.

The problem is:
I put the $values in the `mem:node-replace` but it's not a node, tried xdmp:unquote and other functions but they didn't help.

In this example I show the $values and it's a fine 'path', now how to get this to a node?

```
$doc/*:source/*:content/cdm:BerichtInhoud/cdm:bericht[1]/cdm:id/text()
```

Full example:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace html = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
import module namespace mem = "http://xqdev.com/in-mem-update" at '/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/in-mem-update.xqy';
declare namespace cdm = "http://schemas.dikw.nl/cdm/1.2";

let $key := 'secretkey'
let $doc := 
  <source:source
      xmlns:source="http://marklogic.com/solutions/obi/source">
      <obi:metadata createdBy="admin" createdDateTime="2015-10-16T13:51:30.699172+02:00" lastUpdatedBy="admin" lastUpdatedDateTime="2015-10-16T13:51:30.699172+02:00"
          xmlns:obi="http://marklogic.com/solutions/obi">
      </obi:metadata>
      <source:id>5ac03a41-004a-459b-84b1-4efa8f193847</source:id>
      <dcterms:title
          xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">dikw source data
      </dcterms:title>
      <source:content>
          <cdm:BerichtInhoud xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.dikw.nl/build22.xsd"
              xmlns="http://schemas.dikw.nl/export/1.0"
              xmlns:export="http://schemas.dikw.nl/exporter/1.0"
              xmlns:cdm="http://schemas.dikw.nl/cdm/1.2"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
              <cdm:bericht>
                  <cdm:name>Thijs</cdm:name>
                  <cdm:id>12345</cdm:id>
              </cdm:bericht>
              <cdm:bericht>
                  <cdm:name>Piet</cdm:name>
                  <cdm:id>65756</cdm:id>
              </cdm:bericht>
              <cdm:bericht>
                  <cdm:name>Kees</cdm:name>
                  <cdm:id>87232</cdm:id>
              </cdm:bericht>
          </cdm:BerichtInhoud>
      </source:content>
  </source:source>    

for $singleid in $doc//cdm:id
  
  let $idstring := $singleid/text()

  let $sterk := substring(
    xdmp:hmac-sha512($key, $idstring, 'base64'),
    1, string-length($idstring))

  let $fullpath := xdmp:path($idstring)
  let $values   := fn:concat(fn:string('$doc'), $fullpath)
  let $nodev    := $values

  let $newdoc := mem:node-replace($idstring, <cdm:id>{$sterk}</cdm:id>)

return $values
```

---

### **EDIT**

After some reading and testing on Dave's blog, this is what I came up with. Unfortunatly, it's not working as I'd expect. The code does not change the elements where needed.

The problem is the format in wich the data is given to the local:change() function. Here it is a document and that is why it fails.
I think that in the original code in my project, the type is also a document but I can't be sure because xdmp:describe and xdmp:type do not work.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace mem    = "http://xqdev.com/in-mem-update" at '/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/in-mem-update.xqy';
import module namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com" at "/MarkLogic/functx/functx-1.0-nodoc-2007-01.xqy";

declare namespace cdm = "http://schemas.dikw.nl/cdm/1.2";

declare function local:hashid($id) {
  let $_ := xdmp:log($id)
  let $key := 'secretkey'
  let $idstring := $id/text()

  let $sterk := substring(
    xdmp:hmac-sha512($key, $idstring, 'base64'),
    1, string-length($idstring))

  return $sterk
};

declare function local:change($node)
{
  typeswitch($node)
    (: case on id :)
    case element(cdm:id) return 
    element cdm:id {
      local:hashid($node)
    }
    (: default case, returns unchanged :)
    case element() return 
    element { fn:node-name($node) } {
      $node/@*,
      $node/node() ! local:change(.)
    }
  default return $node
};

declare variable $doc := 
  <source:source
      xmlns:source="http://marklogic.com/solutions/obi/source">
      <obi:metadata createdBy="admin" createdDateTime="2015-10-16T13:51:30.699172+02:00" lastUpdatedBy="admin" lastUpdatedDateTime="2015-10-16T13:51:30.699172+02:00"
          xmlns:obi="http://marklogic.com/solutions/obi">
      </obi:metadata>
      <source:id>5ac03a41-004a-459b-84b1-4efa8f193847</source:id>
      <dcterms:title
          xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">dikw source data
      </dcterms:title>
      <source:content>
          <cdm:BerichtInhoud xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.dikw.nl/build22.xsd"
              xmlns="http://schemas.dikw.nl/export/1.0"
              xmlns:export="http://schemas.dikw.nl/exporter/1.0"
              xmlns:cdm="http://schemas.dikw.nl/cdm/1.2"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
              <cdm:bericht>
                  <cdm:name>Thijs</cdm:name>
                  <cdm:id>12345</cdm:id>
              </cdm:bericht>
              <cdm:bericht>
                  <cdm:name>Piet</cdm:name>
                  <cdm:id>65756</cdm:id>
              </cdm:bericht>
              <cdm:bericht>
                  <cdm:name>Kees</cdm:name>
                  <cdm:id>87232</cdm:id>
              </cdm:bericht>
          </cdm:BerichtInhoud>
      </source:content>
  </source:source>;

return local:change(document {$doc})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the function I came up with in the end with some help from theGeert. The tricky part is the *case document-node()* to tackle that the incoming data is a document.

```
declare function changeid(
  $document
){
  for $node in $document
    let $data :=
      typeswitch($node)
        (: case on the right cdm:id :)
        case element(cdm:id) return
        if ($node/parent::cdm:bericht) then
          element cdm:id {
            hashid($node)
          }
        else ()

        (: root level node :)
        case document-node() return
        document { $node/node() ! changeid(.) }

        (: default case, returns unchanged :)
        case element() return
        element { fn:node-name($node) } {
          $node/@*,
          $node/node() ! changeid(.)
        }
      default return ($node)
  return $data
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed your FLWOR statement to return $newdoc and saw that your ids aren't getting replaced the way you want.

```
<cdm:bericht>
  <cdm:name>Thijs</cdm:name>
  <cdm:id>
    <cdm:id>+CMs5</cdm:id>
  </cdm:id>
</cdm:bericht>
```

What's happening is that the text node under cdm:id is getting replaced with a full node. The solution is to pass in the full node you want to replace. In this case, all you need to do is change:

```
let $idstring := $singleid/text()
```

to

```
let $idstring := $singleid
```

Now $idstring is the whole cdm:id element (and perhaps should be renamed). When you pass that into xdmp:hmac-sha512() and fn:string-length(), it gets cast to a string and you get what you'd expect. If you return $newdoc, your ids will look the way you want:

```
<cdm:bericht>
  <cdm:name>Thijs</cdm:name>
  <cdm:id>+CMs5</cdm:id>
</cdm:bericht>
```

An additional note: since you've got multiple things you want to replace, you should probably tackle this with [recursive descent](http://blog.davidcassel.net/2014/01/recursive-descent-in-xquery/). That way you'll only end up making one copy of the document.

Comment: thanks! I changed the $idstring as you mentioned. My question was actually more about the recursive descent :) I'll take a look at your link!

Comment: I've used some wisdom from your blog, it's in the edit above. The result is still nog what I want but at least it's just another 'type' problem now.